# pandas Add html tables values where data is int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting html table based on day so if I search for 20 days it brings me 20 table and I want to add all 20 tables in 1 table so I can verify data within time series.
I have tried merge and add functions of pandas but it just add as string.

Table one

```
[['\xa0', 'All Issues', 'Investment Grade', 'High Yield', 'Convertible'],
 ['Total Issues Traded', '8039', '5456', '2386', '197'],
 ['Advances', '3834', '2671', '1075', '88'],
 ['Declines', '3668', '2580', '994', '94'],
 ['Unchanged', '163', '54', '99', '10'],
 ['52 Week High', '305', '100', '193', '12'],
 ['52 Week Low', '152', '83', '63', '6'],
 ['Dollar Volume*', '27568', '17000', '9299', '1269']]
```

table two

```
[['\xa0', 'All Issues', 'Investment Grade', 'High Yield', 'Convertible'],
 ['Total Issues Traded', '8039', '5456', '2386', '197'],
 ['Advances', '3834', '2671', '1075', '88'],
 ['Declines', '3668', '2580', '994', '94'],
 ['Unchanged', '163', '54', '99', '10'],
 ['52 Week High', '305', '100', '193', '12'],
 ['52 Week Low', '152', '83', '63', '6'],
 ['Dollar Volume*', '27568', '17000', '9299', '1269']]
```

code but it add as string.

```
tab_data = [[item.text for item in row_data.select("th,td")]
                   for row_data in tables.select("tr")]
df = pd.DataFrame(tab_data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(tab_data)
df3 = df.add(df2,fill_value=0)
df
```

Comment: Instead of using a list comprehension, use a for loop and try to convert values in the table to numbers (float or int) in the loop. Make use of `try/except` to  handle actual strings.

Comment: Can you give me little hint even with pseudo code ?

Comment: In row I have string and number mix how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert the numeric cells into integers, you would need to do that explicitly, as follows:

```
tab_data = [[int(item.text) if item.text.isdigit() else item.text 
                            for item in row_data.select("th,td")]
                            for row_data in tables.select("tr")]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are converting the data frame treats all values as text.
There are two options here.

1. Explicitly convert the strings to the data type you want using [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)
2. Use [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) to create data frames from html tables, which also tries to do the data type conversion.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer but read_html is not working it is same as above.